# npm not installing anything on a certain windows machine

Tags: node.js, windows-7, npm

i have a weird issue with nodejs' npm on one of my windows machines. I cannot install any module, i always get errors.

Let's take the typescript module as an example. On one windows 7 machine (running npm 1.4.3), when i install typescript, it looks like this:

```
C:\Users\myuser>npm install -g typescript
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-1.0.0.tgz
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm
ode_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
typescript@1.0.0 C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript
```

So, it looks Ok, everything works as expected.

Now, on my other windows machine, also running Windows 7, also running npm 1.4.3, it looks like this when i try to install typescript:

```
C:\Users\sbusse>npm install -g typescript
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jake
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jake
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utilities
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utilities
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cover
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/promises-aplus-tests
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opener
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node/1.11.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-uglify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/matcha
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/promises-aplus-tests
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/opener
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node/1.11.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cover
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-uglify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/matcha
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/weak
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/weak
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dateformat/1.0.2-1.2.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hooker
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/exit
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/getobject
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-legacy-util
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/temporary
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-nodeunit
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/difflet
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/2.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/electron
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dateformat/1.0.2-1.2.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-lib-contrib
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/console-browserify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-clean
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-internal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coveraje
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nodeunit
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/slide
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/runforcover
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/difflet
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-equal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon/-/sinon-1.7.3.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hooker
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-growl-reporter
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/walkdir
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gaze
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/requirejs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-reporters
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-nodeunit
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/exit
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/which
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-nodeunit
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon/-/sinon-1.7.3.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/getobject
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-table
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-legacy-util
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/temporary
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-nodeunit
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/difflet
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/2.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/electron
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/drip
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chai-spies
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chai
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-lib-contrib
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/console-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-clean
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-internal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coveraje
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nodeunit
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/difflet
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/slide
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/runforcover
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-equal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-growl-reporter
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/requirejs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/walkdir
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/gaze
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/benchmark
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-reporters
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-nodeunit
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-nodeunit
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-table
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-reporters/-/jasmine-reporters-0.4.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/drip
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chai
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chai-spies
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/read-package-json
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/charm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-is
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ent
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/benchmark
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-reporters/-/jasmine-reporters-0.4.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt/0.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nodelint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/read-package-json
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-is
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/charm
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bunker
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt/0.4.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/package
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon/1.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nodelint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt/-/grunt-0.4.2.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zlib-browserify/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bunker
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/package
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon/1.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zlib-browserify/0.0.1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt/-/grunt-0.4.2.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon/-/sinon-1.2.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint/-/grunt-contrib-jshint-0.8.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon/-/sinon-1.2.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint/-/jshint-2.4.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint/-/grunt-contrib-jshint-0.8.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.3.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint/-/jshint-2.4.4.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tape
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tape
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/folio
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tape
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tape
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/burrito
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/folio
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/codex
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/normalize-package-data
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/burrito
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/codex
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/normalize-package-data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint/-/jshint-2.0.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/codex/-/codex-0.2.3.tgz
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\sbusse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\node_modules\jake\node_modules\q\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\resolve\node_modules\tap\node_modules\di
fflet\node_modules\charm\README.markdown'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "typescript"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\sbusse
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\sbusse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\node_modules\jake\node_modules\q\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\resolve\node_modules\tap\node_modules\difflet\node_module
s\charm\README.markdown
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\sbusse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\node_modules\jake\node_modules\q\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\resolve\node_modules\tap\node_modules\difflet\nod
e_modules\charm\README.markdown
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/codex/-/codex-0.2.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint/-/jshint-2.0.1.tgz
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod 'C:\Users\sbusse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\node_modules\jake\node_modules\q\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\resolve\node_modules\tap\node_modules\gl
ob\glob.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "typescript"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\sbusse
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\sbusse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\node_modules\jake\node_modules\q\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\resolve\node_modules\tap\node_modules\glob\glob.js
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\Users\sbusse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\node_modules\jake\node_modules\q\node_modules\grunt-cli\node_modules\resolve\node_modules\tap\node_modules\glob\glob.j
s
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
^CBatchvorgang abbrechen (J/N)? j
```

I stopped the process here, because it will run forever. Seriously, i let it run for 20 minutes and it wouldn't stop.

Now i have tried numerous things. Obviously de- and reinstalling nodejs, cleaning cache, deleting the whole npm and/or node_modules folders, installing older versions of nodejs and npm, but no luck. I also experimented with using the 32 or 64 bit versions of nodejs, but it made no difference. The windows machines also have the same state of windows updates installed. There is definitely something wrong with my second windows machine, but I don't know how to debug and find the cause. I am out of ideas.

Does anyone know, what the issue might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well not a solution really, but I think, I found a workaround. I had the "dev" config turned to true, which installs all devDependencies. Perhaps this is just too much dependencies for windows?!

If I turn that of, I can install typescript and other modules I couldn't before, like grunt or angular.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

Compare the npm config on both machines:

```
npm config ls -l
```

Compare the environment path on both machines:

```
echo $env:path
```

Reduce the global package installation configuration:

> The Node installer installs, directly into the npm folder, a special piece of Windows-specific configuration that tells npm where to install global packages. When npm is used to install itself, it is supposed to copy this special builtin configuration into the new install. There was a bug in some versions of npm that kept this from working, so you may need to go in and fix that up by hand. If %APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc does not exist, you'll need to create it yourself. (%APPDATA% defaults to :\Users\\AppData\Roaming). All you need to put in that file is:
>
> prefix=${APPDATA}/npm
>
> Incidentally, if you would prefer that packages not be installed to your roaming profile (because you have a quota on your shared network, or it makes logging in or out from a domain sluggish), you can put it in your local app data instead:
>
> prefix=${LOCALAPPDATA}/npm
>
> ...as well as copying %APPDATA%\npm to %LOCALAPPDATA%\npm (and updating your %PATH%, of course).
>
> Everyone who works on npm knows that this process is complicated and fraught, and we're working on making it simpler. Stay tuned.

**References**

- [Troubleshooting NPM](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)